# Getting error while trying to install packages using sudo apt-get

Tags: apt

My ubuntu version is:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

I am getting the following error while trying to install

> E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/atlas/libatlas3-base_3.10.3-5_amd64.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:ffff::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)

Searching in the web for similar errors suggested that I have to url

> in.archive.ubuntu.com

and

> security.ubuntu.com

with

> old-releases.ubuntu.com

But my Ubuntu version is the latest one. I don't think network connection is an issue.Any help would be appreciated

Comment: "*(101: Network is unreachable)*" means that your network does indeed seem to be an issue.

Comment: FYI: Your system likely isn't fully upgraded though, as it'd respond 18.04.4 not 18.04.3

Comment: I ran the following comments sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade before installing, is there anything else I have to do. Also, maybe network is not an issue because I am able to write this because of the same internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My internet connection was LAN and maybe the firewall blocked access. However, when I try to install over wifi, it works. My bad, I should I have tried it before

Comment: Good job figuring it out!